# convert dataset into nested xml???Help me

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have 1 dataset, named Invoices, of 2 datatable, the data is taken from sql server 2008. Ignoring the data from the database, I focus on the dataset exported to xml. Datatable 1, named Invoice,  includes OrderID, CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerPhone.
Datatable 2, named Products, includes ProductID, OrderID, ProductName , Price, Quantity, Amount.
My Question is, I want to get this output,

```
<Invoices>
    <OrderID>1</OrderID>
    <Invoice>
        <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>A</CustomerName>
        <CustomerPhone>123</CustomerPhone>
        <Products>
            <Product>
                <ProductID>1</ProductID>
                <ProductName>C</ProductName>
                <Price>10</Price>
                <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                <Amount>20</Amount>
            </Product>
        </Products>
        <TotalAmount>20</TotalAmount> --TotalAmount = sum(amount of products)
    </Invoice>
    <OrderID>2</OrderID>
    <Invoice>
        <CustomerID>3</CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>D</CustomerName>
        <CustomerPhone>1789</CustomerPhone>
        <Products>
            <Product>
                <ProductID>5</ProductID>
                <ProductName>V</ProductName>
                <Price>30</Price>
                <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                <Amount>90</Amount>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <ProductID>9</ProductID>
                <ProductName>Z</ProductName>
                <Price>5</Price>
                <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                <Amount>20</Amount>
            </Product>
        </Products>
        <TotalAmount>110</TotalAmount> --TotalAmount = sum(amount of products)
    </Invoice>      
</Invoices>
```

But I get this output:

```
<Invoices>
    <OrderID>1</OrderID>
    <Invoice>
        <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>A</CustomerName>
        <CustomerPhone>123</CustomerPhone>      
        <TotalAmount>20</TotalAmount> --TotalAmount = sum(amount of products)
        <Products>
            <Product>
                <ProductID>1</ProductID>
                <ProductName>C</ProductName>
                <Price>10</Price>
                <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                <Amount>20</Amount>
            </Product>
        </Products>
    </Invoice>
    <OrderID>2</OrderID>
    <Invoice>
        <CustomerID>3</CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>D</CustomerName>
        <CustomerPhone>1789</CustomerPhone>     
        <TotalAmount>110</TotalAmount> --TotalAmount = sum(amount of products)
        <Products>
            <Product>
                <ProductID>5</ProductID>
                <ProductName>V</ProductName>
                <Price>30</Price>
                <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                <Amount>90</Amount>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <ProductID>9</ProductID>
                <ProductName>Z</ProductName>
                <Price>5</Price>
                <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                <Amount>20</Amount>
            </Product>
        </Products>
    </Invoice>      
</Invoices>
```

The code to export xml is:

```
public DataSet LoadInvoices()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Invoices");

            DataTable dt1 = LoadInvoice();
            dt1.TableName = "Invoice";


            DataTable dt3 = LoadProduct();
            dt3.TableName = "Product";

            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt3);


            DataColumn colDT3 = dt3.Columns[2];
            DataColumn colDT21 = dt1.Columns[0];
            DataRelation rel2 = new DataRelation("PRODUCT"
                      , colDT21, colDT3);
            rel2.Nested = true;
            ds.Relations.Add(rel2);

            return ds;
        }

  public string xmlConvert(DataSet ds)
        {
            string sXML = "";

            sXML = ds.GetXml();

            return sXML;
        }
```

Therefore, I have to adjust the code to export the xml as I want???

Comment: Where's your code? You need to include a [mcve]. Take a look at the [help] and [ask].

Comment: A dataset like `System.Data.Dataset` (I think that's right). Datasets have their own view of what XML should look like. You might have to go back to where you're getting the data from and use a more modern data access methodology (in order to get it into a structure you can *shape*)

Comment: You have to include a minimal code so that we can understand where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm a newbie, so i don't know how to ask. I will edit my question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid xml since it contains and ampersand.  Should be & The issue probably can be fixed in the dataset query but do not have enough info on the methods that were used to create the xml.  You always can edit the xml code Using xml linq to filter output :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> removeItems = doc.Descendants("catname").Where(x => (string)x != "Hotel").ToList();
            removeItems.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```